# Postgress—add two rows simultaneously in two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

### Background

I have two tables: `posts` and `post_contents`. Every post has one current "contents", and every "contents" relates to one post. With this setup, you can save multiple versions of every post, and at the same time make sure there's only one canonical version of the metadata.

```sql
-- note: this won't strictly work since you can't reference a table that's not yet created, but it shows the overall structure.
create table posts (
  id uuid primary key,
  current_contents uuid not null references post_contents(id)
);

create table post_contents (
  id uuid primary key,
  post uuid not null references posts(id),
  contents text
);
```

When a post is updated, a new draft should be added to the `post_contents` table, and the original `posts` row should be updated to point to the new draft.

```
create or replace function update_post(id uuid, contents text)
  returns uuid as $id$
  declare contents_id uuid;
  begin
    insert into post_contents
      (id, post, contents) values (generate_uuid(), id, contents)
      returning id into contents_id;

    update posts
      set current_contents = contents_id
      where posts.id = id;

    return contents_id;
  end;
$id$ language plpgsql;
```

### Issue

This works well when updating a post, but not for adding a post. If you try to add a row to the `posts` table first, there aren't any contents to reference, violating the `not null` constraint. Or if you create the contents row first, you get the same problem because you don't have a post to attach the contents to.

### Goal

Is there a way to add these two rows into the two table simultaneously? That way, the foreign key relationships work.

**Possible solutions**

1. It is possible to just make sure one of the foreign key `current_contents references post_contents(id)` is nullable. This would work but it's not ideal as then you don't have the guarantee that every post has contents.
2. To make the guarantee, you could implement row level security. Inserts don't need the foreign key, but updates do.
3. Alternatively, you could create a dummy post_contents row. Then you could then first create the post, referencing the dummy content, then create the contents referencing the post, and finally update the post to reference the true contents.

I'll do #3 if it's not possible to add the two row simultaneously, but I'd rather keep `not null` in the schema if at all possible.

Comment: Disable autocommit, make inserting into both tables together a transaction?

Comment: http://dbadailystuff.com/deferred-constraints-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

You can set the FK constraint to `DEFERRABLE` to defer its enforcement until commit time. [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html). Example, `ALTER TABLE post ALTER CONSTRAINT current_contents_fkey DEFERRABLE;`

But for what you describe, it's standard practice to avoid circular relationships in your tables. That'd mean making `post_contents` refer to `post` but not the other way around. I implemented this exact same feature in my app last week. I also created a convenient view of the latest contents for each post using something like

```
CREATE VIEW latest_post_contents AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(p.id) p.id, pc.contents
  FROM post p, post_content pc
  WHERE p.id = pc.post_id
  ORDER BY p.id, pc.id DESC  -- latest post_content row for this post
);
```

Also, this way you're never updating or deleting rows, only inserting, which has a variety of advantages.

**Edit:** You asked about performance. Unless the query planner is somehow tricked, this should take the O(nlogn) time to sort the post contents only for the posts a query is returning, meaning it's fast as long as there aren't insane numbers of edits.

However, turns out that view tricks the planner in a simple case where I want to filter posts by index. Say `post` has some other field `oid`, a client-facing UUID that's indexed. If you `SELECT * FROM latest_post_contents WHERE oid = '...'`, it sorts all the `post_contents` then filters, which seems bad since there's only one post you care about. If you directly join and filter yourself, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(p.id) p.id, pc.contents
  FROM post p, post_content pc
  WHERE p.id = pc.post_id
  AND p.oid = '...'
  ORDER BY p.id, pc.id DESC
```

... it filters by OID first then sorts, making it basically as fast as if you had that double reference if there aren't tons of edits. On my DB, that was about 70X faster than using the view.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on post_info_latest  (cost=21459.48..21713.49 rows=56 width=607) (actual time=647.491..780.271 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (post_info_latest.oid = 'f76ee62b-51b6-466e-bffe-640daefcd7a6'::uuid)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 11262
   ->  Unique  (cost=21459.48..21572.46 rows=11283 width=615) (actual time=647.479..773.254 rows=11263 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=21459.48..21515.97 rows=22596 width=615) (actual time=647.474..737.061 rows=45184 loops=1)
               Sort Key: p.id, pi.id DESC
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 27712kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.73..13644.36 rows=22596 width=615) (actual time=0.099..281.356 rows=45184 loops=1)
                     ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.44..507.56 rows=5632 width=32) (actual time=0.064..32.268 rows=11263 loops=1)
                           Merge Cond: (p.id = pd.post)
                           ->  Index Scan using post_pkey on post p  (cost=0.29..398.25 rows=11264 width=32) (actual time=0.036..15.565 rows=11264 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Only Scan using post_deletion_post on post_deletion pd  (cost=0.15..66.15 rows=1200 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                                 Heap Fetches: 1
                     ->  Index Scan using post_info_post on post_info pi  (cost=0.29..2.29 rows=4 width=583) (actual time=0.006..0.014 rows=4 loops=11263)
                           Index Cond: (post = p.id)
 Planning Time: 1.322 ms
 Execution Time: 808.986 ms
(17 rows)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=461.27..461.28 rows=2 width=615) (actual time=11.665..11.729 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=461.27..461.27 rows=2 width=615) (actual time=11.654..11.690 rows=12 loops=1)
         Sort Key: p.id, pi.id DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.77..461.26 rows=2 width=615) (actual time=0.109..11.592 rows=12 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=4.48..441.65 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.079..11.465 rows=1 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using post_pkey on post p  (cost=0.29..426.41 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.043..11.417 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Filter: (oid = 'f76ee62b-51b6-466e-bffe-640daefcd7a6'::uuid)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 11263
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on post_deletion pd  (cost=4.20..13.67 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (post = p.id)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on post_deletion_post  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (post = p.id)
               ->  Index Scan using post_info_post on post_info pi  (cost=0.29..19.57 rows=4 width=583) (actual time=0.020..0.073 rows=12 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (post = p.id)
 Planning Time: 1.279 ms
 Execution Time: 11.893 ms
(17 rows)
```

Postgres 11. My dev DB is on my Raspberry Pi's SD card. On a real DB, you'll probably need much more than my 11K rows to see such a difference ;)

Comment: That would work. Do you know if there are any noticeable performance issues from needing to sort all the contents every time someone views the post? I figured with the circular setup + indexing, getting the latest contents is a constant time operation. But if your suggestion doesn't have noticeable performance drawbacks, I'll use it.

Comment: @Nick Sorting is O(nlogn), but Postgres will usually be smart enough to do the sort at the end, so it's fine as long as there isn't a huge number of edits on one post. As always, it's possible the denormalized version becomes faster if your DB is huge, but it's better to cross that bridge only if you get there, i.e. you add another table tracking the latest `post_content` for each `post` if you notice slowness.

Comment: Note that omitting the reference to `post_contents` in `post`, which is declared `NOT NULL`, won't enforce that every post has to have at least one content any longer. So that technically isn't a 100% equivalent to what the OP has now.

Comment: Yes. Your transaction will ensure at least one `post_contents` per `post`, but there's no constraint enforcing it if some other statement messes that up. Actually I just made my app disregard orphaned `post` rows anyway.

Comment: @Nick Actually, what I said about Postgres being smart and sorting at the end isn't true if you query from the view instead of just joining manually. See the edit.

Comment: I forget sometimes how knowledgable and helpful people are on Stackoverflow. I think I'm going to remove the circular dependency and create a third table to connect a post with it's contents. It also gives the added feature of being able to rollback the current contents to previous versions (instead of deleting rows in `post_contents`).

Comment: Well, I caught something wrong with my app in the process. I was using views in my other queries. Now I know where to look if things get slow.

Comment: @Nick BTW why not to keep the recent content in the `post` itself and use `post_content` only for previous versions (which used not so frequently)?

Comment: @Abelisto That works too, but it's a bit less clean. You end up with two tables with the same columns in them, and you have to copy data from one to another transactionally. If you're denormalizing things for performance (which both ideas are), best to keep that piece small and self-contained like Nick is doing.